# how to center the button inside a table cell

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center a button inside the table by : `text-align: center`

However, it seems doesn't work for me.

Note:  I used `Display: table-cell` combine with `Vertical-align: middle` to center the text of the button. As you can see the text of the first button "AAAAAAA" is in the middle.

Can someone help me to center the button without affecting the text of the button.
Thank you in advance.

Here's the example code:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pAcBx

Comment: `display:table-cell;` Why would you do that?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫: because I want the text in the button to be vertically middle as well, please re-visit the link, I just did the a little modify to the first button text.

Comment: I see. Just like most of the people, I believe you misunderstood the meaning of `vertical-align`. It is not for aligning the content vertically; it's for telling the browser how to treat inline blocks on the character baseline.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I usually do

```
  margin:auto;
  display:block;
```

I guess @rhino answer works as well. Remember to remove

```
  display:table-cell;
```

**EDIT:**

Keep in mind that doing this will get the `a` element **content** vertically centered, but if you also give the `a` element an arbitrary height, the surrounding background will not be centered.

Example 1: the text **is** vertically centered. But you set the button height to 32px and that surrounding container isn't:

```css
table, tr, td{
  border: solid;
 
}
.my_table {
 width: 312px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.dashed {
  border-bottom:1px dashed #99F;
  width:100%;
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  font-size:0;
  top:43px;
}

/*BUTTON TABLE left CELL*/
.left_button_cell{
  margin: 0 auto;
 text-align: center;     /*<---- NOT WORKING */
 height: 50px;
 padding-top: 10px;
 line-height: 22px;
}


/*BUTTON TABLE right CELL*/
.right_button_cell{
 text-align: center; 
 height: 50px;
 padding-top: 10px;
 line-height: 22px;
}

.inner_button {
 -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
 -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
 box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
 background-color:#fbfbfb;
 -webkit-border-top-left-radius:8px;
 -moz-border-radius-topleft:8px;
 border-top-left-radius:8px;
 -webkit-border-top-right-radius:8px;
 -moz-border-radius-topright:8px;
 border-top-right-radius:8px;
 -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:8px;
 -moz-border-radius-bottomright:8px;
 border-bottom-right-radius:8px;
 -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:8px;
 -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:8px;
 border-bottom-left-radius:8px;
 text-indent:0;
 border:2px solid #dcdcdc;
 display:block;
  margin:auto;
 color:#939393;
 font-family:arial;
 font-size:15px;
 font-weight:normal;
 font-style:normal;
 height:32px;
 line-height:16px;
 width:104px;
 text-decoration:none;
 text-align:center;
 text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #ffffff;
 word-wrap:break-word;
 vertical-align:middle;
}

 
.inner_button:hover {
 background-color:#EBEBEB;
}
.inner_button:active {
 position:relative;
 top:1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dashed"></div>
<table class="my_table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="left_button_cell">
        <a class="inner_button" href="#">AAAAAAAA</a>
        </td>
      <td class="right_button_cell">
      <a class="inner_button" href="#">BBBBBBBB BBBBBBBB</a>
      </td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You could set the line-height to be also 32px, which would work for the first button, but the second one would break. Also, you could set a button padding of 6px to achieve the same result without declaring an explicit height (as css frameworks like bootstrap or materialize do) but the line break on the second button would result in uneven button sizes.

**So, here's my suggested trick**: set the `a` element line height to be 32px, then wrap its inner text in a `span` element where you reset the line-height to 16px:

```css
table, tr, td{
  border: solid;
 
}
.my_table {
 width: 312px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

/*BUTTON TABLE left CELL*/
.left_button_cell{
  margin: 0 auto;
 text-align: center;     /*<---- NOT WORKING */
 height: 50px;
 padding-top: 10px;
 line-height: 22px;
}


/*BUTTON TABLE right CELL*/
.right_button_cell{
 text-align: center; 
 height: 50px;
 padding-top: 10px;
 line-height: 22px;
}

.inner_button {
 -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
 -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
 box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
 background-color:#fbfbfb;
 -webkit-border-top-left-radius:8px;
 -moz-border-radius-topleft:8px;
 border-top-left-radius:8px;
 -webkit-border-top-right-radius:8px;
 -moz-border-radius-topright:8px;
 border-top-right-radius:8px;
 -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:8px;
 -moz-border-radius-bottomright:8px;
 border-bottom-right-radius:8px;
 -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:8px;
 -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:8px;
 border-bottom-left-radius:8px;
 text-indent:0;
 border:2px solid #dcdcdc;
 display:block;
  margin: 0 auto;
 color:#939393;
 font-family:arial;
 font-size:15px;
 font-weight:normal;
 font-style:normal;
 height:32px;
 line-height:32px;
 width:104px;
 text-decoration:none;
 text-align:center;
 text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #ffffff;
 word-wrap:break-word;
 vertical-align:middle;
}

.inner_button span {
  line-height:16px;
  display:inline-block;
}
.inner_button:hover {
 background-color:#EBEBEB;
}
.inner_button:active {
 position:relative;
 top:1px;
}
```

```html
<table class="my_table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="left_button_cell">
        <a class="inner_button" href="#">
          <span>AAAAAAAA
                  </span>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td class="right_button_cell">
        <a class="inner_button" href="#">
          <span>BBBBBBBB BBBBBBBB</span>
        </a>
      </td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**EDIT 2019**

You can achieve the same using flexbox. However, this means the border-spacing property does no longer apply so you need to do some fine tuning to the cell margins.

Basically, you set flex properties as:

```
.my_table tr {
  display:flex;
}

.my_table td {
  margin: 2px;
  height: 60px;
  display:flex;
  flex-grow:1;
  /* centering the button */
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}


.inner_button {
  display:flex;
  /* centering the text inside the button */
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;

  /* plus the other properties */
}
```

With this you no longer need playing with spans, and the alignment of children is controlled explicitly.

```css
table,  td{
  border: solid;
 
}
.my_table {
 width: 312px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.my_table tr {
  display:flex;
}
 
.my_table td {
  margin: 2px;
  height: 60px;
  display:flex;
  flex-grow:1;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
 

.inner_button {
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  display:flex;
  width:104px;
  box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
  background-color:#fbfbfb;
  text-align:center;
  border-radius:8px; 
  border:2px solid #dcdcdc;
  color:#939393;
 font-family:arial;
 font-size:15px;
 height:45px;
 text-decoration:none;
 text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #ffffff;
 word-wrap:break-word;
 
}

.inner_button:hover {
 background-color:#EBEBEB;
}
.inner_button:active {
 position:relative;
 top:1px;
}
```

```html
<table class="my_table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="left_button_cell">
        <a class="inner_button" href="#">
       AAAAAAAA
                
        </a>
      </td>
      <td class="right_button_cell">
        <a class="inner_button" href="#">
         BBBBBBBB BBBBBBBB
        </a>
      </td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Anyway, once you switch to this layout there's no reason to stick to tables, and you might as well convert your layout to divs.

Comment: hmmm,  I used 'display:table-cell' to middle the text of the button, I did a little modify to the first button, please revisit the example link, you'll see the problem.

Comment: I tried on your example. Replacing table-cell for block, and adding margin:auto did the trick for me.

Comment: but the text of the button would not be centered. I want to keep the text of the button centered as well as the position of the button.

Comment: @shensw I'm sorry I took 4 years to answer your comment. I edited my answer to help you achieve the desired results.

Answer (score 2):

Change `display: table-cell` to `display: inline-block`:

```
.inner_button {
    /* ... */
    display: inline-block;
    /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added this to the TableCell and it centered my ImageButton.  I think we were running into the same issue.

```
<asp:TableCell HorizontalAlign="Center" style="padding: 0px;">
    <asp:ImageButton/>
</asp:TableCell>
```

Found my answer here: [http://forums.asp.net/t/1418752.aspx?image+button+inside+table+cell](http://forums.asp.net/t/1418752.aspx?image%20button%20inside%20table%20cell)

Answer (score -2):

You can use the `table-cell` display property of the container div and set the `vertical-align` property to `middle`:

**HTML**

```
<div id="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">
            <a href="">I'm your button</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#table {
    width: 300px;
    display: table;
    background: red;
}

.row {
    display: table-row;
}

.cell {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 200px;
    background: yellow;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

You can find [the fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/3z3Ws/).

Answer (score -3):

this works

```
 td{
   align:center;
 }
```

simple and easy... hope it helps

Comment: i tested in the link that you provided... AND it seems to be working to me ... can you check it again.

Comment: I double checked, doesn't work for me, I want the text of the button to be centered as well as "the button itself", and I think you meant `align-content: center` property, I tried that with Chrome as well (`align-content` only supported by Ohrome and Opera), still not working , thank you for your suggestion though